# Data-driven tests in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, yaml, data-driven-tests

I've got to test a message-routing application, whose functionality is broadly as follows:
- message gets sent to app
- app examines message
- message gets forwarded somewhere, based on the content of the message

The vast majority of test cases are near-identical; generate a particular type of message, load it into the system, wait a few seconds, then check the required destination to ensure that the message was forwarded correctly.

Rather than generate 100s of near-identical test cases in Cucumber, is there a recommended way to generate the one test case, and have it repeatedly cycle through all the (message, required_destination) tuples?  I'd prefer to have these tuples maintained into a YAML file rather than a database, for ease of maintenance, but either solution would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try **Scenario Outline** using **Examples**

**Normal Scenario**

```
Scenario: Login
  Given I am on login page
  When I enter username "Jonas" and password "secrect" and press login
  Then I get redirected to "Jonas Home Page"
```

**Scenario Outline**

```
Scenario Outline: Login
  Given I am on login page
  When I enter username <username> and password <password> and press login
  Then I get redirected to <redirect_page>

Examples:
  | username | password | redirect_page     |
  | "Jonas"  | "secret" | "Jonas Home Page" |
  | "Anna"   | "Data"   | "Annas Home Page" |
```

Read More:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

Answer (score 0):

I dont have this kind of situation in cucumber, but I do use pipe separated files in specs for massive data testing, hope it will help:

You can find examples [here in description of DamerauLevenshteinMod](http://github.com/dimus/taxamatch_rb/blob/4e409172cd3288f52a8d037bc9a56ad405c0a5e2/spec/taxamatch_rb_spec.rb) and [here in read_test_file](http://github.com/dimus/biodiversity/blob/a364b82351a4cee6309c522a682d29b51c3d9920/spec/parser/scientific_name.spec.rb)

I dont see why the same approach cannot be used for cucumber as well.

Comment: Thanks Dimus.  I can think of a number of possible ways of doing it - for that matter, having code walk through my YAML file and write a new Cucumber scenario for each message type would work just fine - but I'm primarily interested to find out if there's a Cucumber "native" or "recommended" way of achieving it.